# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Access denied

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### want to

Eliminate this error,
I want to connect rails and MySQL

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Access denied for user 'wdyluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'wdyluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

### Current status

I'm making an app with rails.
DB used SQLite at first, but decided to move to MySQL.

Finally,When I typed this command, I got the above error and got stuck.

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

↓

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Access denied for user 'wdyluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'wdyluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

### Source

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: wdyldb
  username: wdyluser
  password: 00000
  host: 127.0.0.1
  encoding: utf8

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2'
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
```

### I tried

- Can I log in to MySQL

```
mysql -uwdyluser -p00000
```

↓

ok (username and its password are correct)

- Does DB exist

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| wdyldb             |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

↓
Exists

- Does user exist and is it authorized?

```
mysql> show grants for wdyluser@localhost;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for wdyluser@localhost                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `wdyluser`@`localhost`                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wdyldb`.* TO `wdyluser`@`localhost` |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

↓
Exists, has authority

### environment

macOS BigSur 11.1
mysql  Ver 8.0.23
ruby 2.7.0p0
Rails 6.1.1

Comment: Have you tried quoting your password in the database.yml file: `password: "00000"`?

Comment: i put a comma, you succeed!!thankyou

Comment: There's no comma in your code above?.... But I suspect `00000` was being interpreted as the number zero, not a string.

Comment: Try using a text editor with proper syntax highlighting. It would have immediately shown you the fact that the datatype is a number and not a string.

Comment: Don't put "how to solve" in the title. That is the entire, singular purpose of this site.